# how to define the search correctly with "xml.etree.ElementTree" when the number of tags of the .xml tree increases

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following python script that parses an .xml and returns the fragment that is between 2 tags (profile) according to a given id:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")

# Iterate over all 'profile' elements
for profile in tree.findall("profile"):
    id = profile.find("id").text
    if "Georgia" in id:
    print(ET.tostring(profile).decode())
```

whose output is:

```
<profile>
  <id>Georgia-1</id>
<activation>
  <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
   <profile>Georgia-p1</profile>
   <showtitle>Georgia_s1</showtitle>
   <ip>000.000.0.3</ip>
   <port>00003</port>
   <persistencePort>00033</persistencePort>
   <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
   <webstart.server.name>host_3</webstart.server.name>
   <codebaseProtocolServer>T3</codebaseProtocolServer>
   </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
   <id>Georgia-2</id>
<activation>
   <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
    <profile>Georgia-p2</profile>
    <showtitle>Georgia_s2</showtitle>
    <ip>000.000.0.4</ip>
    <port>00004</port>
    <persistencePort>00044</persistencePort>
    <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
    <webstart.server.name>host_4</webstart.server.name>
    <codebaseProtocolServer>T4</codebaseProtocolServer>
</properties>
</profile>
```

So far everything is correct, the output is as desired. The problem appears when the number of tree tags increases for this scrypt like in this example where the `<profiles></profiles>` tag is added:

```
<project>       

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>Azerbaiyan-1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            <profile>Azerbaiyan-p1</profile>
            <showtitle>Azerbaiyan_s1</showtitle>
            <ip>000.000.0.1</ip>
            <port>00001</port>
            <persistencePort>00011</persistencePort>
            <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
            <webstart.server.name>host_1</webstart.server.name>
            <codebaseProtocolServer>T1</codebaseProtocolServer>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>Azerbaiyan-2</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            <profile>Azerbaiyan-p2</profile>
            <showtitle>Azerbaiyan_s2</showtitle>
            <ip>000.000.0.2</ip>
            <port>00002</port>
            <persistencePort>00022</persistencePort>
            <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
            <webstart.server.name>host_2</webstart.server.name>
            <codebaseProtocolServer>T2</codebaseProtocolServer>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>Georgia-1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            <profile>Georgia-p1</profile>
            <showtitle>Georgia_s1</showtitle>
            <ip>000.000.0.3</ip>
            <port>00003</port>
            <persistencePort>00033</persistencePort>
            <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
            <webstart.server.name>host_3</webstart.server.name>
            <codebaseProtocolServer>T3</codebaseProtocolServer>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>Georgia-2</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            <profile>Georgia-p2</profile>
            <showtitle>Georgia_s2</showtitle>
            <ip>000.000.0.4</ip>
            <port>00004</port>
            <persistencePort>00044</persistencePort>
            <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
            <webstart.server.name>host_4</webstart.server.name>
            <codebaseProtocolServer>T4</codebaseProtocolServer>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>USA-1</id>
            <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            <profile>USA-p1</profile>
            <showtitle>USA1_s1</showtitle>
            <ip>000.000.0.5</ip>
            <port>00005</port>
            <persistencePort>00055</persistencePort>
            <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
            <webstart.server.name>host_5</webstart.server.name>
            <codebaseProtocolServer>T5</codebaseProtocolServer>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>USA-2</id>
            <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            <profile>USA-p2</profile>
            <showtitle>USA1_s2</showtitle>
            <ip>000.000.0.6</ip>
            <port>00006</port>
            <persistencePort>00066</persistencePort>
            <defaultLocale>en_GB</defaultLocale>
            <webstart.server.name>host_6</webstart.server.name>
            <codebaseProtocolServer>T6</codebaseProtocolServer>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</project>
```

and I don't know how to adapt the previous script so that it goes beyond the "profiles" tag to be able to reach the "profile" tag, which is where the tree should actually be parsed as in the initial script

Comment: The answer to "Does xml.etree.ElementTree in python have problems with certain .xml tags?" is "no". That's all we can say. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok @mzjn
I am going to try to reduce the point of error to be able to bring the example in a reduced form and thus be able to try to be located. Right now I haven't been able to do it because I've removed an important fragment from the end of the .xml file in which a multitude of labels are found, it's almost like killing a fly with a cannonball...
I will try to reduce the problem area and share it, thanks and sorry.

Comment: I think I have already found the problem... I update the query

Comment: Instead of `tree.findall("profile")`, I think you need `tree.findall(".//profile")`. The first expression searches only immediate children of the root element. The other searches for `profile` elements everywhere in the XML document.

Comment: I have been trying and pulling the thread with what you have indicated and it seems that just like that it does not work but with `tree.findall("./*profile")` it does seem to work! I'll keep trying in this direction, thanks!